# Does having a separate CSS file have an effect on the code running?

Tags: html, css

I am learning CSS and HTML, and I was creating a template locally, first time I had a separate local CSS file, in this file the body will not be styled but a div was, the second time I tried to include the CSS in the HTML body and not in a separate CSS file and everything worked fine.

First time, the div was styled but the body was not.when a separate CSS file was created:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Quote Machine</title>
    <script src="scripting.js"></script> 
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js"   integrity="sha256-laXWtGydpwqJ8JA+X9x2miwmaiKhn8tVmOVEigRNtP4="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>hello</div>
<style>
</style>
</body>
</html>

<!-- separate CSS file-->
    body {
        background-color:black;
    }   


div {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Second time, everything was styled as required when the CSS was inside the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Quote Machine</title>        
    <script src="scripting.js"></script> 
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js"   integrity="sha256-laXWtGydpwqJ8JA+X9x2miwmaiKhn8tVmOVEigRNtP4="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div>hello</div>

<style>

body {
    background-color:black;
}   

div {
    background-color:yellow;
}

</style>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include your stylesheet *after* the bootstrap one for it to override the default bootstrap styling.

What's happening in your first example is it's loading your stylesheet, then loading the bootstrap stylesheet.

In the second example, it's loading your stylesheet, then the bootstrap stylesheet, then overriding the bootstrap stylesheet with the styling you've declared in the html.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to M P's answer, in your second example, using  elements as child tags of  tags is not proper html.  They  elements belong in the  section.

Answer (score 1):

Your **style.css is comimg before your bootstrap file** . **This needs to be the other way around** . The reason your style is working internally is because the dom is compiled last and will override any external styles that do not include !important .

**Example**

**4rd Priority**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

**3rd Priority**

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

**2nd Priority**

```
<head>
<style></style>
</head>
```

**1st Priority**

```
<div style="color:red;"></div>
```

All work in this order .

Hope this helps